# Display link icon for a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know it might be easy but I can't find how to do it.

How can I display a link icon for a cell?
Both cells are on the same spreadsheet.

For example:
A1 should have a calculator image and link to cell G1.

when I insert an image I don't have the option to link to somewhere else.
HYPERLINK not working because it's not a hyperlink.
IMPORTRANGE doesn't works for me when I link the same spreadsheet to itself.

Please your advice
[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get a link to the cell, you can do that by performing the following.

[image: Right click > More actions > Get Link to Cell]

Then Use that as the Hyperlink URL, and a reference to an image as the text to display

[image: Result]

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jUchM8h6Y8U17eBM-J1RydjQS4nae_5ktNb4G6vNv4U/edit#gid=0&range=I1", M2)
```

Comment: I have issue with the Link, not with the picture.
I've added a screenshot for reference